# How can I default/focus to a button with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Does anyone know how can I default/focus a button by using jquery?

If I have a page with 3 input box and 3 button for difference action. How could I default the button when the user enter value into the input box.

Example:
Based in the following code, let say when the use key in the value under age input, then pressed enter instead of clicked on the search button (ID="btnAgeSearch") to do the search. How could I default/focus the button to (ID="btnAgeSearch"), so that the system will call btnAgeSearch_Click function to do the search instead button (ID="btnNameSearch") or button (ID="btnColorSearch").

```
<table border="0" width="900px">
        <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="sName" runat="server" Width="150px" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnNameSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnNameSearch_Click"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Or<br />Age: </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="sAge" runat="server" Width="150px" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnAgeSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnAgeSearch_Click"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Or<br />Color: </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="sColor" runat="server" Width="150px" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnColorSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnColorSearch_Click"/>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'default the button'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function buttonClicked(e) {
    code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        setTimeout(function () { $('#btnNameSearch').click(); }, 0);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then on add an keydown event onkeydown="return buttonClicked(event);".

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to let the browser handle this automatically rather than using jQuery. Surround your input and button pairs with a `<form>` element, and set the type of the button to `type="submit"`:

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <asp:TextBox ID="sColor" runat="server" Width="150px" />
    <asp:Button type="submit" ID="btnColorSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnColorSearch_Click"/>
</form>
```